# Replication Synchronization in Memgraph: Inclusion of Indexes, Constraints, and Migrations

Tags: memgraphdb

I am working with a replication setup in Memgraph, and I've come across an uncertainty regarding the synchronization process between instances.

My question is whether or not indexes, constraints, migrations, and similar configurations are also synchronized along with the data during replication. If I configure these aspects (indexes, migrations, constraints, etc.) on the main instance, can I safely assume that the replicas will automatically replicate these changes?

Is the synchronization process in Memgraph's replication setup inclusive of just the data or does it also account for the aforementioned configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is enough to configure the main instance with indexes, migrations, constraints etc. To verify, you can check that by running appropriate queries on replica instances (e.g., `SHOW INDEX INFO`).